# iOS OTA build not downloading

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ota

It's a little weird problem. Today i built new version of my iOS application for OTA distribution. After downloading suddenly it says "**Unable to Download App, 'ABC' could not be downloaded at this time**". But the weird thing is it works if i use xCode "**Devices**" tool to install the same ipa file. I checked, double checked below things and still it's not working.

1. Recreated new provisioning profile.
2. Add different device and created new provisioning profile.
3. Use different mac to build the application.
4. Use different Apple developer account to build the app.(Created app id, prov profile, etc...)
5. Even i created an empty application to see if i modified any build settings by mistake.
6. Regenerated `manifest.plist` file.
7. Checked the html file to see if i linked to correct plist file.
8. Also server has valid SSL certificate installed.

This is my manifest.plist file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://example.com/app/abc.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://example.com/app/</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://example.com/app/</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.example.ap</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>ABC</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And this is my html link,

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.example.com/app/manifest.plist">Tap Here to Install ABC Application</a>
```

Comment: Does the server you are hosting the app on have an SSL certificate?

Comment: @AlexBrown, I i have installed SSL certificate, and it's valid.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't see that last point. I've always found OTA builds to be rather  fickle myself, I recently switched to using https://www.diawi.com/ and haven't looked back, not sure if that's applicable in your situation.

Comment: Thanks @AlexBrown, I have to go with our own distribution system though.

Comment: Do you delete it off the device first? I find OTA downloads don't work if i already have the app installed via Xcode.

Comment: @JamesP, As far as i know that doesn't matter. But yeah, the app wasn't there when i'm downloading from the OTA link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sorted out the problem. Actually that's a silly one :)

The only mistake i did was not adding '`www`', It works fine once i add it.

I had to use "https://www.exam....." everywhere.